Excel select cells within filtered cells
I want to select cells within filtered cells.
Example

This is my code
Sub GoToNextVisibleCellBelow()
    
    Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub

It goes down 1 column within the column I selected. I can run this code as many times as necessary for more. However, as seen in the picture, although I could move left and right in the filtered cells, I could not select upwards.
What should I do to select an area like in the picture?

Firstly, why do you need selecting cells in a filtered visible area? Secondly, you did not specify which to be your initial selected cell. A1? Then, your code tries selecting cell by cell. In your picture there is a large selected area. As the selection looks in the picture, you did not select only the visible cells. What do you really try doing, please?

I wonder how you can make the selection seen in the picture with vba? I want to make the selection and delete the data in that field.

But what do you understand by selection? The visible cells of the filtered range? Part of the respective filtered range? Or what? Even so, why needing selecting to delete? Do you understand the difference between delete and clear?


Selecting the range is not necessary in most case.

How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

The filtered table could be non-contiguous.
Use nested loops to iterate through areas and rows to collect the target copying range.
Assume the table starts from cell A1.

Microsoft documentation:

Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)


Range.Areas property (Excel)


Application.Union method (Excel)


Range.EntireRow property (Excel)

Option Explicit

Sub DelTopNRows()
    Dim visRng As Range, selRng As Range, iR As Long
    Dim ColCnt As Long, rRow As Range, rArea As Range
    Const ROWS_CNT = 4  ' modify as needed
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        ColCnt = .Columns.Count
        ' get the visible range after filtering
        Set visRng = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
            ' check if the cnt of visible rows > desired rows
            If visRng.Cells.Count / ColCnt > ROWS_CNT Then
                ' loop through areas > rows
                For Each rArea In visRng.Areas
                    For Each rRow In rArea.Rows
                        ' collect target rows range
                        If selRng Is Nothing Then
                            Set selRng = rRow
                        Else
                            Set selRng = Application.Union(selRng, rRow)
                        End If
                        iR = iR + 1
                        If iR = ROWS_CNT Then Exit For
                    Next
                    If iR = ROWS_CNT Then Exit For
                Next
            Else
                Set selRng = visRng
            End If
            ' delete rows
            If Not selRng Is Nothing Then selRng.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub



